# How to enable a LLVM backend?

Tags: llvm

I am using Archlinux and installed LLVM using the official package (using `pacman -S llvm`).
I'd like to use it with the `wasm-32` backend ([available according to the source code](https://llvm.org/doxygen/Triple_8h_source.html)).

However, this backend is not enabled on my computer:

```
$ llc --version
LLVM (http://llvm.org/):
  LLVM version 5.0.0
  Optimized build.
  Default target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  Host CPU: skylake

  Registered Targets:
    aarch64    - AArch64 (little endian)
    aarch64_be - AArch64 (big endian)
    amdgcn     - AMD GCN GPUs
    arm        - ARM
    arm64      - ARM64 (little endian)
    armeb      - ARM (big endian)
    bpf        - BPF (host endian)
    bpfeb      - BPF (big endian)
    bpfel      - BPF (little endian)
    hexagon    - Hexagon
    lanai      - Lanai
    mips       - Mips
    mips64     - Mips64 [experimental]
    mips64el   - Mips64el [experimental]
    mipsel     - Mipsel
    msp430     - MSP430 [experimental]
    nvptx      - NVIDIA PTX 32-bit
    nvptx64    - NVIDIA PTX 64-bit
    ppc32      - PowerPC 32
    ppc64      - PowerPC 64
    ppc64le    - PowerPC 64 LE
    r600       - AMD GPUs HD2XXX-HD6XXX
    sparc      - Sparc
    sparcel    - Sparc LE
    sparcv9    - Sparc V9
    systemz    - SystemZ
    thumb      - Thumb
    thumbeb    - Thumb (big endian)
    x86        - 32-bit X86: Pentium-Pro and above
    x86-64     - 64-bit X86: EM64T and AMD64
    xcore      - XCore
```

How can I enable LLVM backends?

Comment: Compile your own copy with the appropriate backend enabled?

Comment: @tambre Ok, I was hoping that there was an easier way to do it. But my question still stands then: how can I simply build LLVM with custom targets?

Comment: Oh please. For a relatively simple question, it is hardly documented. Search engines return noise when searching for how to compile LLVM because it's a compiler itself. It also turns out that beyond basics, they're documentation is lacking: to enable the wasm target you need to use a variable that isn't even documented (`LLVM_EXPERIMENTAL_TARGETS_TO_BUILD`).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**EDIT (2021-07-23)**: This answer was updated to use "Motorola 68000" instead of "WebAssembly" as an example experimental target (since Wasm is now stable).

LLVM is not very configurable once it is built.
If you need a configuration beyond the defaults, **you have to compile LLVM yourself**.

LLVM has a few articles explaining how to compile it, but it does not describe exactly
how to enable additional targets:

- [Getting Started](https://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html#getting-started-quickly-a-summary)
- [Building LLVM with CMake](https://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html#quick-start)

The enabled targets are controlled by two variables that you need to define when invoking CMake
to prepare the build directory: `LLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD` and `LLVM_EXPERIMENTAL_TARGETS_TO_BUILD`.

- `LLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD` controls *only the stable* targets.
  You can either use the special value `all` to enable all the *stable* targets or provide a semicolon-separated list of targets such as `ARM;PowerPC;X86`. There is [an old request](https://reviews.llvm.org/D34910)
  to rename the special value to `stable` and use `all` for *all* the targets.
  Its default value is `all` (see below for the list of targets).
- `LLVM_EXPERIMENTAL_TARGETS_TO_BUILD` is an undocumented (or well hidden) variable that allows you
  to enable any target you want. This is also a semicolon-separated list of targets.

The enabled targets will correspond to the union of both lists.

Now, you need to find out the actual name of your target and if it is a stable or experimental target.
The list of stable targets can be found [in the Getting Started article](https://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html#local-llvm-configuration).

> The default value includes: `AArch64`, `AMDGPU`, `ARM`, `AVR`, `BPF`, `Hexagon`, `Lanai`, `Mips`, `MSP430`, `NVPTX`, `PowerPC`, `RISCV`, `Sparc`, `SystemZ`, `WebAssembly`, `X86`, `XCore`.

This list is defined in [the main CMakeFile (permalink)](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/91bc85b1ebaaa4e61058c24b556d6f0569a9b091/llvm/CMakeLists.txt#L305).

As you can see, `WebAssembly` is in the list now (in 2021), so it should already be enabled by default. When the question was first asked, it was still an experimental target.

**When the question was first asked, `WebAssembly` was still an experimental target so the rest of the answer will more generally describe how to enable any target. As an example, we'll use "Motorola 68000" instead of wasm.**

"Motorola 68000" is not in the list of stable targets. We'll have to find the name used by LLVM and then use `LLVM_EXPERIMENTAL_TARGETS_TO_BUILD`.
Unfortunately, since this variable is not documented, I wasn't able to find the list of *all* the targets on their website.
After some trial and error, it seems that **the available targets correspond to the names of the directories in [`/lib/Target`](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/tree/main/llvm/lib/Target)**. This directory contains a subdirectory named `M68k`: this is likely the name of the target.

To use LLVM for "Motorola 68000", you'll need to enable the `M68k` target using the `LLVM_EXPERIMENTAL_TARGETS_TO_BUILD`
variable when preparing the build directory with CMake.

---

Here are the steps to compile LLVM with "Motorola 68000" support (adapt it to your own requirements). I used a Linux machine
but you should be able to adapt it to your environment.

Requirements:

- [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/)
- Git
- GCC, CLang or Visual Studio depending on your platform
- zlib

1. Clone the LLVM repo. I'll use the `/opt/llvm-project` directory for the home directory
   of my custom version of LLVM (this is the last argument to the command, replace it by the path you want to use).

   `git clone https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git /opt/llvm-project`
2. Navigate to the LLVM sources:

   `cd /opt/llvm-project/llvm`
3. Create your build directory and navigate to it.

   `mkdir build && cd build`
4. **Use CMake to prepare your build directory**. This is the step where you need take care
   of setting the variables. In my case I'll use `LLVM_EXPERIMENTAL_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="M68k"` and
   leave `LLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD` to its default value (all stable targets).
   Another important variable that I'll set is `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` to get an optimized build and
   `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/llvm-project/llvm/bin` to keep this version of LLVM in its directory and do
   not interfere with the version I already have on my system (I'll just add this directory to the $PATH
   when I'll need it).

   `cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DLLVM_EXPERIMENTAL_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="M68k" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/llvm-project/llvm/bin -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release /opt/llvm-project/llvm`
5. Build LLVM, this may take a while:

   `cmake --build .`
6. Install LLVM:

   `cmake --build . --target install`

Comment: hello does this method add the backend target into llvm-tblgen ? I have tried target "Xtensa", but seems still treated as "unknown target"

Answer (score 3):

You should compile your backend from source. The only pluggable things in LLVM are passes currently.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll upvote but I'm about to post a longer post detailing how to enable targets: it turns out that it's not that obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Your *llc --version* command says that you installed LLVM version 5.0.0. WASM wasn't integrated into LLVM until LLVM 8.0.0. It was experimental before that.

> Changes to the WebAssembly Target
>
> The WebAssembly target is no longer “experimental”! It’s now built by
> default, rather than needing to be enabled with
> LLVM_EXPERIMENTAL_TARGETS_TO_BUILD.
>
> The object file format and core C ABI are now considered stable. That
> said, the object file format has an ABI versioning capability, and one
> anticipated use for it will be to add support for returning small
> structs as multiple return values, once the underlying WebAssembly
> platform itself supports it. Additionally, multithreading support is
> not yet included in the stable ABI.

https://releases.llvm.org/8.0.1/docs/ReleaseNotes.html#changes-to-the-webassembly-target

Comment: If you need to specifically use the WebAssembly target, I agree that there is nothing to do. However, the question is more general and asks how to enable any target.